# Creation and display of song setlists

Tags: nodes, entities, theming

I am using Drupal version 7.42 and a content type used for information regarding **Concert setlists**. It includes labels for:

- Date.
- Venue.
- Location.
- Setlist.
- Description.
- Lineup.

I will give you an idea of what I am looking to achieve in the end regarding its display. I also have a content type for the **Songs**.

Each **performance listing** will be different. I will have some listings that show **Songs** known to be performed yet the **Setlist** isn't complete. I will have some listings that show songs known to be performed in:

- Set 1.
- Set 2.
- Encore.
- etc.

Also, some performances may have more than one encore, so I also will have performances noted with Encore 1, Encore 2, etc. if the listing requires it.

***How do I manage to get the display of the setlist to show a label above the songs indicating the song placement?***

I thought having multiple fields in the content type (Set 1, Encore, Encore 1, Encore 2, etc) does the trick. But with time mulling over this one I am thinking is it possible to be achieved by just having one setlist field (Setlist) instead of multiple setlist fields in the content section?

Below is an example of the display I am describing for site viewers to see when visiting a performance page. Each song listed in a performance page at the moment uses [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) to link to its unique song within the Songs content type.

- Set:

  - Song 1
  - Song 2
  - Song 3
- Encore 1:

  - Song 4
  - Song 5
- Encore 2:

  - Song 6

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you aware that the rule around here (on this site) is like "1 question at a time"? It's fine to ask (post) multiple questions at once though (and linking from one question to another as like a related or followup question) ... By splitting your questions, you also have a choice of picking (= marking as accepted) the answer that best fits for a specific question. That's not possible by posting the 3 questions together ... Maybe you should MOVE question 2 and 3 to a separated one? Even if it was only because otherwise your question may be put on hold with reason like (eg) "Too broad" ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens fixed. sorry about the mishap. thank you for the tips!

Comment: OK, thank you for taking my advice ... Now we are cooking! Next: let's start to think about an answer ... PS: where did the other 2 questions go ???

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens i understand your reasoning and took your advice about splitting up questions, so i removed them for now. i will ask the other two later on once this one gets answered. one question at a time.

Comment: I tried to improve the formatting of your question, please review/check it, and further adapt/refine where appropriate. Worst case: perform a "rollback" (to completely undo my edits). PS: while doing so, I also posted an answer ... Curious about your feedback about it ...

Comment: I think it might help if you also (briefly) explain what you mean by "performance" (and "performance listing"). Also, the "set" and "encore" occurrences are a (very little) bit hard to understand, maybe you can think of some replacement of it (at least the "Encore", the French for "some more" ???). Also: "setlists" and "listings", so many "list"-things ...

Comment: is **set**, **encore 1** and **encore 2** seperate entity references fields?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens thank you. i will review your module and see if it fits my idea. thank you. by "performance" i am talking about a concert performance - the show that is performed. set, encore and all tie into song placement of a set list. an artist will perform a main set then usually take a break for an encore where they perform a few more songs. also, thank you for formatting my question to make it easier for the eyes. my mistake.

Comment: @NoSssweat Yes. I have the following separate entity reference fields within the Tour content type:

**Set 1** (also known as the main set of a concert performance)  
**Set 2** (i have this one in the event an artist has two sets within a performance)  
**Encore** (i have this field in the event the show has strictly one encore)  
**Encore 1** (the field is to mark the first encore if another one takes place after it)  
**Encore 2** (the field marks the second encore)

Comment: Aha, now I get the "encore" part of it, it's really like in French ... But around here they just call that "bis", "bis", "bis" (variation: "we want more", "we want more" ...). PS: not "my" module (I'm just a co-maintainer) ...

Answer (score 0):

Below is a possible approach you may want to consider. It's using "State" names (like Florida, Illinois, etc.) instead of "Set 1, Set 2, etc" and "Cities" instead of "Songs".

If I was to implement this in a Drupal site, I'd use either of these "displays":

- **Option 1 - Master detail with nested blocks**

  Have a look at [this example](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.state_breakdown), which shows 1 "block" for each "State", and within each "block" it shows the "Cities" (and one of its attributes) in that "State".
- **Option 2 - Report that filters based on some lookup**

  Have a look at [this example](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/sample.user_distribution_simple?state=IL), which shows only the data about a specific "State", together with all the "Cities" (and one of its attributes) in that "State". To switch to another state, select the desired state from the Parameter form near the top ("IL" is used as the default in this example).

If you wonder "**How did you do that?!?!**" ... then this is the answer: that's really a piece of cake using the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module. Checkout the [Community Documentation](https://drupal.org/node/2041363) for details, and/or the [documentation that comes with the module](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help). The above 2 examples are actually delivered with the module (out-of-the-forena-box), though you probably don't notice that it is even not a typical "Drupal database". It could be such database instead, but in this case it's an SQLite (sample) database (it could also have been Oracle, MS SQL, Postgress or any PDO compliant database).

**Disclosure**: I'm a co-maintainer of Forena.

Answer (score 0):

### [Views tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree)

> This module provides a tree-based style plugin for Views. It is
> equivalent to the tree-based style template from Views 1.
>
> It is based off of the list style. Although it generates a nested
> view, there is still only a single query run for the view making it
> quite performant.
>
> #### Compatibility
>
> This module has been tested and used with the following
> relationship-oriented modules:
>
> - Taxonomy (in core) - parent/child relationships References - node and
>   user references Relation
> - references between any entities (D7 only)
> - Entity reference - references between any entities (D7 only)
> - Organic Groups (D7 only)
>
> Example:
>
> [image]